# Prevent FxCop from accessing GotDotNet

Tags: fxcop

I'm running FxCop and it fails on error code 16777217.
A [quick Googling](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/ff0e0580-8c81-4557-983e-95ef9e30dbd7) reveals that this is because FxCop tries to access a website at gotdotnet.com.

I'm using FxCop from the command line (actually wrapped in an MsBuild community task). How do I make it not access gotdotnet site from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

What version of FxCop are you running?  The current version (1.36) was released after gotdotnet was shut down, so there should no longer be references to that site.  You can currently find the download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9AEAA970-F281-4FB0-ABA1-D59D7ED09772&displaylang=en)